# Schedule AWS Lambda on a repeated but temporary basis

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, scheduled-tasks, amazon-cloudwatch

I know it's possible to [make a Lambda function run on a schedule using CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) (which basically simulates CRON).

However, would it be possible to do so on a temporary basis, based on a manual trigger? For example, "click a button" to run a Lambda function every hour, but only for the next 48 hours - and then stop, and not start again until a human "presses the button".

The "button" could create a CloudWatch rule using the API, but how can I make the rule stop automatically/by itself after 48 hours?

Example of CloudWatch rule creation:

```
aws events put-rule \
--name my-scheduled-rule \
--schedule-expression 'rate(1 hour)'
```

Comment: Perhaps you could write the Lambda function so that the last thing it does is to check an environment variable or Parameter Store for a decommission/die time. When it exceeds that time it would remove the CloudWatch scheduled event. Next time you want to start it up, your start process writes the new decommission/die time and then you configure CloudWatch to again schedule the Lambda.

Comment: Oh, that would work! Mind posting it as an answer?

Comment: Or, just create 48 non-repeating events!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: That would work too! It's a bit trickier as the duration can be dynamic, but wouldn't be too hard to implement with a simple loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could write the Lambda function so that the last thing it does is to check an environment variable or Parameter Store for a decommission/die time. When it exceeds that time it would remove the CloudWatch scheduled event. Next time you want to start it up, your start process writes the new decommission/die time and then you configure CloudWatch to again schedule the Lambda.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be to use an AWS Step Function to trigger the disabling/deletion of the initial/repeating CloudWatch event, [as described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56937218/aws-lambda-schedule-a-delayed-execution-to-run-once).

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use create a second CloudWatch event triggered via CRON & scheduled to run once in the future (i.e. 48 hours from now), [as explained in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47880716/invoke-aws-lambda-function-only-once-at-a-single-specified-future-time).

This could trigger a Lambda function which would disable or delete the initial, repeating CloudWatch schedule.

Answer (score 1):

Using Step functions is a clean work but there is also a smart way I have recently seen some articles about to use a feature in DynamoDB as explained here for Ad-hoc scheduled tasks that might work for your case too: https://theburningmonk.com/2019/03/dynamodb-ttl-as-an-ad-hoc-scheduling-mechanism/